# How to get rid of "Invalid opcode 0x002A at PC=0x004" in ISIS Proteus?

Tags: avr, embedded, atmega, c, proteus

I have used ATmega 8 and have simulated a circuit to use interrupts, when i give an external interrupt i.e. when a push button is pressed all the LEDs connected to PORTB supposed to be lit up, but i am getting this error, What to do?
This is the code i have used

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#define F_CPU 4000000UL
#define DataDDR     DDRB


#define DataPort    PORTB
ISR(INT0_vect)
{
    unsigned char i, temp;

    _delay_ms(500); // Software debouncing control

    temp = DataPort;    // Save current value on DataPort

    /* This for loop blink LEDs on Dataport 5 times*/
    for(; ; )
    {

        DataPort = 0xFF;

    }

    DataPort = temp;    //Restore old value to DataPort 
}   

int main(void)
{
    DDRD = 1<<PD2;      // Set PD2 as input (Using for interupt INT0)
    PORTD = 1<<PD2;     // Enable PD2 pull-up resistor

    DataDDR = 0xFF;     // Configure Dataport as output
    DataPort = 0x01;    // Initialise Dataport to 1

    GICR = 1<<INT0;                 // Enable INT0
    MCUCR = 1<<ISC01 | 1<<ISC00;    // Trigger INT0 on rising edge

    sei();              //Enable Global Interrupt

    while(1)
    {
        if(DataPort >= 0x80)
            DataPort = 1;
        else
            DataPort = DataPort << 1;   // Shift to the left

        _delay_ms(500); // Wait 5 seconds

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: it's been posted, please have a look

Comment: There's no way to ever exit the interrupt handler, although I don't think that's causing your problem.

Comment: Are you sure you compiled the program for the same controller as ISIS Proteus is configured?

Comment: yes i have cross checked that! , it is running but when an interrupt is given , it fails and shows error

Comment: Seems as if there is a bad instruction in the Interrupt Vector Table. The meaning of that table varies per controller. It contains the instruction that will be executed when the interrupt is triggered.

Comment: Might be a little late, but try selecting "default" option in BOOTRST, from the microcontroller "Edit Component" configuration window.

Comment: Problem is when you compile your code you must chose right bord, be sure its matching your board, if Uno then not use Mega etc..